# Google Earth Plug-In: SUCCESS_RECENT_INSTALL_RESTART

Tags: iframe, https, google-earth-plugin

I use the google earth-plug-in, in combination with google maps. All works fine for Firefox or Chrome, but in IE7, IE8 the google earth plugin crashes. 
At the moment I make a workaround and disabled the whole google earth-plugin in this error case.  I embeded the site (https://tandemx-science.dlr.de/DEMDataTake_Request_template05.html) in a iframe on my mainsite. Someone knows the matter of the crash in ie7 and ie8 (error below)?

The google failureCallback delivers this error: "SUCCESS_RECENT_INSTALL_RESTART"

Link to the contain of the iframe: https://tandemx-science.dlr.de/dem-datatake/DEMDataTake_Request_template05.html
If i call it over this link, all works fine, but embeeded in my main site it crashes.
(I can't post the link to the main site, cause the functionality is only avaible for users of the site)

```
    SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/ErrorPageTemplate.css 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/ErrorPageTemplate.css 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/errorPageStrings.js 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/errorPageStrings.js 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/httpErrorPagesScripts.js 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/httpErrorPagesScripts.js 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/noConnect.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/down.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/favcenter.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/favcenter.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/noConnect.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/down.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/favcenter.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/favcenter.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/background_gradient.jpg 
SEC7111: HTTPS-Sicherheit beeinträchtigt durch res://ieframe.dll/background_gradient.jpg 
SCRIPT16389: Zugriff verweigert

DEMDataTake_Request_template05.html, Zeile 1 Zeichen 1
```

I hope someone can help my.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is....really strange. I put the iframe in another iframe and it works.
So i made a wrapper page witch put the "interface-page" in another iframe.

The final solution was to update all plugins from the WCM.